# Exclude specific articles / categories from smart search

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, smartsearch

I was wondering if it's possible to exclude specific articles and/or categories from my smart search.

For example I have a category named 'Uncategorised' that I would like to be 'non-searchable'. I also have an article called 'Mailing List' which is in the category 'Mailing', I would like this one specific article to be excluded from search also.

I've had a look at the option in the Smart Search plugin but can't find any?

I know this was possible with Joomla 2.5 by selecting Search - Content plugin > 'No' for the Uncategorised Articles.

Any help appreciated.

(update - a free option would be preferable if at all possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smart search component does an index of your sites pages, so makes a new list just to search from. The normal search searches your live articles.

This means you can go in to the index and remove pages you dont want. So look on this page and tick and delete the pages you dont want.

```
YOURWEBSITE.. /administrator/index.php?option=com_finder
```

You can also tell it which categories not to index in the first place. In Content Maps you can click on "Categories" link and then untick on the right the ones you dont want.

```
YOURWBSITE... /administrator/index.php?option=com_finder&view=maps
```

I for example only ever index articles and not tags and categories so i remove those options.

Comment: Thanks @tristanbailey I think this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3):

**Paid Option: "Search Content Advanced"**

You should take a look at an extension called "[Search Content Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/19759)". I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it can do exactly the kind of filtering you're looking for. (It's not free, though).

**Free Option: Joomla Smart Search**

I had a quick look at the Joomla Smart Search function included in Joomla 3, maybe you can set up a filter that fits your needs, but it's not very intuitive. To create a Smart Search filter:

1. Enable the `Smart Search` plugins from the Plugin manager.
2. Go to Administrator -> Components -> Smart Search. Make sure you index your content at least once (`Index` button on the toolbar).
3. Click `Search Filters` on the left side and create a new filter.
4. You'll be able to set some filtering rules based on your content, but as far as I can see there's no `exclude` function, only `include`.
5. Save your filter, and create a Smart Search module (or menu item). You filter should be available in the "Search Filter" field.

**Bottom line:** The Search Content Advanced extension looks like a better option for your needs, it's a lot more flexible and easier to use than the Joomla Smart Search component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion johanpw, although I should have mentioned I would prefer a free option. I'm surprised that there is no in built functionality within Joomla, it seems overly-complicated. That extension does look good though (pity it's not free!). I will try your suggestion tomorrow though and report back.

Comment: I dont understand @johnny_s that is part of Joomla, it is free, thats how you can use it.